# Code smell in AngularJS custom directive

Tags: angularjs

In the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app10" ng-cloak>
    <head>
        <title>Custom directives</title>
        <style>
            [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as o">
            <div  bb-player-list="bbPlayers" array-item="name | uppercase" ng-model="o"> 

            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/exam10.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
var app10 = angular.module("app10", []);


app10.directive("bbPlayerList", DirectiveFunction);

function DirectiveFunction(){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
            var data  = "";
            if(attrs["ngModel"] === "")
                data = scope[attrs["bbPlayerList"]];
            else
                data = scope[attrs["ngModel"]][attrs["bbPlayerList"]];

    }
}

app10.controller("mainCtrl", MainController);

function MainController(){
    this.bbPlayers = [
        {name: "Barry Bonds", avg: 0.298, hr: 762, obp: 0.444},
        {name: "Hank Aaron", avg: 0.305, hr: 755, obp: 0.374},
        {name: "Babe Ruth", avg: 0.342, hr: 714, obp: 0.474},
        {name: "Ted Williams", avg: 0.344, hr: 521, obp: 0.482}
    ];


}
```

---

In `DirectiveFunction`, there is a code smell in retrieving the data using `ngModel`,

```
    var data  = "";
    if(attrs["ngModel"] === "")
        data = scope[attrs["bbPlayerList"]];
    else
        data = scope[attrs["ngModel"]][attrs["bbPlayerList"]];
```

Reason to add this code smell is,

if controller is instantiated like `mainCtrl as o` then `ngModel` would be `"o"` otherwise `ngModel` will be `""`. This attribute `ngModel` will decide, how to access `bbPlayers` in `DirectiveFunction`?

Can I avoid this code smell in `DirectiveFunction`?

How does `DirectiveFunction` get immune to, the way `mainCtrl` is instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider `require`-ing the `ngModel`controller (and the `MainController`, if needed) inside your directive definition instead of inspecting the `attrs` inside of the `link` function:

```js
function DirectiveFunction(){
  return {
    require: [ '^ngController', '?ngModel' ],
    link: (scope, element, attrs, controllers) => {
      const [ MainController, ngModel ] = controllers;

      data = main.bbPlayers;
    }
  };
}
```

It appears that you're trying to share data between controllers, however, which is best done through a shared, named service. Consider instead:

```js
angular.module('app10')
  .factory('Players', function(){ // injectable, if you need it...
    return [
      {name: "Barry Bonds", avg: 0.298, hr: 762, obp: 0.444},
      {name: "Hank Aaron", avg: 0.305, hr: 755, obp: 0.374},
      {name: "Babe Ruth", avg: 0.342, hr: 714, obp: 0.474},
      {name: "Ted Williams", avg: 0.344, hr: 521, obp: 0.482}
    ];
  })
  .directive('bbPlayerList', function(){ // also injectable...
    return {
      controller: function(Players){ // injectable again...
        // Do stuff with `Players` if you need to...
      }
    }
  });
```

If you need to fetch the data from a server and cache the results, you can put that logic in the setup of `Players` or expose a method that will do the same:

```js
angular.module('app10')
  .factory('Players', function(){ // injectable again...
    return {
      all: () => [
        {name: "Barry Bonds", avg: 0.298, hr: 762, obp: 0.444},
        {name: "Hank Aaron", avg: 0.305, hr: 755, obp: 0.374},
        {name: "Babe Ruth", avg: 0.342, hr: 714, obp: 0.474},
        {name: "Ted Williams", avg: 0.344, hr: 521, obp: 0.482}
      ]
    };
  });
```

Then call `Players.all()` inside any constructor to get all the players. You can easily replace the dummy data with a call to an endpoint with `$http` or `$resource` or Restangular.